# Javascript after X click in button to go

Tags: javascript, html, function

How can i make the function for this button:

```
<input id="btntest" type="button" value="Check" onclick="return btntest_onclick()" />
```

so that after 30 click's redirects me to a different page.

Comment: How about a variable which will be incremented after every click ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a global variable:

```
var counter = 0;

function btn_test_onclick(){
    if(counter === 30){
        window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
    } else {
       counter++;
    }
}
```

Here's some info on [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

Comment: No need to use else for count++ variable you can declare before if or after . it is possible. for better I think should declare count++ before conditional

Comment: @Rinkaslb,

No need to use else and count++ should be declare before if brother

Answer (score 0):

```
     <script>
         var count = 0;
        function btntest_onclick(){
            count++;
            if(count ==12){
               window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
<input id="btntest" type="button" value="Check" onclick="return btntest_onclick()" />


<script>

var btntest_onclick = (function () {
    var i = 1;

    return function () {
      alert(i);
       i++;
        if(i>30){
           window.location = "www.google.com";
          }
    }
})();
</script>
```